# Connect SharePoint calendar to O365 Outlook Calendar

Tags: 2013, office-365, calendar, outlook

Is it possible to connect a SharePoint site calendar to your personal O365 Outlook calendar?

When trying to add a calendar via O365 it prompts you to add an .ics address.

[image]

I've tried using the URL of the calendar but it doesn't recognize the .aspx page as a calendar.  I've looked into seeing if there is a hidden .ics address that can be used but haven't had any luck.

I want this to be a live link so exporting the calendar and adding it from file won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the site>choose the site Calendar>Calendar (in the tab)> Click on the button "Connect to Outlook":

[image]

The calendar should appear in Outlook under Other Calendars like this:

[image]

Comment: The 'Connect to Outlook' function doesn't work in this case (or hasn't with everything I've tested), in that we need this to sync with users' iOS devices.  We've found that adding the calendar using this function doesn't add it to an iPhone/iPad, but adding from O365 will for some reason.